# MariaDB Connection Pool Gets Exhausted After A While

Tags: python

I am using MariaDB Database Connector for Python and I have a singleton database class that is responsible for creating a pool and performing database operations on that pool. I have made every effort to close the pool after every access. But, still, after a while the pool becomes unusable and gets stuck, never to be freed. This might be a bug with the connector or a bug in my code. Once the pool is exhausted, I create and return a normal connection, which is not efficient for every database access.

Here's my database module code:

```
import mariadb 

import configparser
import sys


from classes.logger import AppLogger

logger = AppLogger(__name__)

connections = 0

class Db:
    """
    Main database for the application
    """   
    
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('/app/config/conf.ini')
    db_config = db_config = config['db']
    try:
        conn_pool = mariadb.ConnectionPool( 
            user = db_config['user'],
            password = db_config['password'],
            host = db_config['host'],
            port = int(db_config['port']),
            pool_name = db_config['pool_name'],
            pool_size = int(db_config['pool_size']),
            database = db_config['database'],
        )
    except mariadb.PoolError as e:
        print(f'Error creating connection pool: {e}')
        logger.error(f'Error creating connection pool: {e}')
        sys.exit(1)


    def get_pool(self):
            return self.conn_pool if self.conn_pool != None else self.create_pool()
    def __get_connection__(self):
        """
        Returns a db connection
        """

        global connections
        try:
            pconn = self.conn_pool.get_connection()
            pconn.autocommit = True
            print(f"Receiving connection. Auto commit: {pconn.autocommit}")
            connections += 1
            print(f"New Connection. Open Connections: {connections}")
            logger.debug(f"New Connection. Open Connections: {connections}")
        except mariadb.PoolError as e:
            print(f"Error getting pool connection: {e}")
            logger.error(f'Error getting pool connection: {e}')
            # exit(1)
            pconn = self.ــcreate_connectionــ()
            pconn.autocommit = True
            connections += 1
            logger.debug(f'Created normal connection following failed pool access. Connections: {connections}')
        return pconn

        
    def ــcreate_connectionــ(self):
        """
        Creates a new connection. Use this when getting a
         pool connection fails
        """
        db_config = self.db_config
        return  mariadb.connect(
                user = db_config['user'],
                password = db_config['password'],
                host = db_config['host'],
                port = int(db_config['port']),
                database = db_config['database'],
            )

    def exec_sql(self, sql, values = None):
        global connections
        pconn = self.__get_connection__()
        try:        
            cur = pconn.cursor()
            print(f'Sql: {sql}')
            print(f'values: {values}')
            cur.execute(sql, values)
            # pconn.commit()
            # Is this a select operation?
            if sql.startswith('SELECT') or sql.startswith('Select') or sql.startswith('select'):
                result = cur.fetchall() #Return a result set for select operations
            else: 
                result = True
                
            pconn.close()
            connections -= 1
            print(f'connection closed: connections: {connections}')
            logger.debug(f'connection closed: connections: {connections}')
            # return True #Return true for insert, update, and delete operations 
            return result
        except mariadb.Error as e:
            print(f"Error performing database operations: {e}")
            # pconn.rollback()
            pconn.close()
            connections -=1
            print(f'connection closed: connections: {connections}')     
            return False
```

To use the class in a module,  I import the class there and simply instantiate an object from the class and run sql queries on it:

```
db = Db()
users = db.exec_sql("SELECT * FROM users")
```

Any ideas why the pool gets exhausted after a while (maybe days) and never gets healed?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a different error from `mariadb.Error` is raised sometimes and the connection is never closed. I believe the best practice would be to use a `finally` section to guarantee that the connection is always closed, like this:

```python
pconn = None
try:
    pconn = self.__get_connection__()
    # ...
except mariadb.Error as e:
    # ...
finally:
    if pconn:
        try:
            pconn.close()
        except:
            # Not really expected, but if this ever happens it should not alter
            # whatever happened in the try or except sections above.
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But, I'm quite sure it's pool error as I see it in logs, but maybe some error happens before that. The finally clause should be useful anyways.

Comment: The finally part will run whether or not an exception occurred. So, the connection will always be closed, which is not what I want.

Comment: @codezombie, I disagree. `close()` returns the connection to the pool according to [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy/api/ConnectionPool/):  "Threads using the pool fetch a connection via [get_connection()](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy/api/get_connection/#conpy-api-get-connection) and return it to the pool by calling [close()](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy/api/close/#conpy-api-close) on the connection (or using the default close on the object's destruction)".

Comment: Sorry my bad. I was talking about the body of__get_connection(). You're right. The connection in exec_sql() must close eventually.