# Cannot recreate a MariaDB ConnectionPool

Tags: python, mariadb, connection-pooling

I have a script that calls 3 methods. In those methods I have the first that uses a mariadb connectionPool, the second calls a single connection and the third again a connectionPool. In the main method I don't create connections, they are all inside the methods. All the pool connections are closed. However, when it arrives at the third method, when it open the pool,  the process hangs and simply dies without giving any error. I followed the example [here](https://mariadb.com/docs/reference/conpy/api/ConnectionPool/). The same behavior happens even if I only call the same method two times as in the example below.

```
import mariadb

def first():
    # it dies here the second time
    pool = mariadb.ConnectionPool(
        pool_name = 'pool1',
        pool_size = 3,
        pool_reset_connection = False,
        host = '127.0.0.1',
        user = 'root',
        password = 'secret',
        database = 'test',
    )

    # These would normally be allocated in separate threads:
    conn1 = pool.get_connection()
    conn2 = pool.get_connection()
    conn3 = pool.get_connection()
    # Attempting to fetch a 4th connection would throw an exception
    # given the pool_size == 3 option above.

    cursor = conn1.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?)', (1, 2))

    cursor = conn2.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?)', (3, 4))

    cursor = conn3.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO sample VALUES (?, ?)', (5, 6))

    conn1.commit()
    conn2.commit()
    conn3.commit()

    conn1.close()
    conn2.close()
    conn3.close()


def main():
    first()
    first()
```

I think that it doesn't really destroy the pool or it remains open for the database but I didn't find anything about and it doesn't raise any exception. Does anyone know how I can destroy/close the pool to reuse it?

Comment: Shouldn't you `commit` the changes to the database?

Comment: @T0ny1234 Yes, with the insert I have to call `commit` but that's not the point. If I call `close` without `commit` the connection is closed in any case, saving or not the insert queries

Comment: add an error hadling with `try` `except mariadb.Error` to see whether there is an error that you can't see. Like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303760/mariadb-connection-pool-gets-exhausted-after-a-while)

Answer (score 0):

So, this is weird. I ran in debug my code without remembering that I had some breakpoints, after an half hour I returned to my computer, the process was still running and blocked after the first call but before the third (of the original problem), I continued the run and it ran completing all without dying.

So the problem should be mariaDB, not python, maybe the pool isn't really closed but after a while it goes in timeout and it is again available.

Following this intuition I tried something similar, I gave unique names to the pools I used, i.e. change the `pool_name` parameter when creating the pool. I tried running the algorithm and it went to the end without any errors.

So, I don't know if it exists but as we can create a pool in mariaDB we should be able as well to close/destroy it